# Why is Git ignoring my Makefile?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to include Makefile in my git repo, but I get this message:

```
$ git add Makefile
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Makefile
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

In my repo `.gitignore` file I have:

```
*.pdf
```

In my ~/.gitignore_global

```
#-*-shell-script-*-

# Python
*.pyc

# Latex
*.aux
*.bbl
*.blg
*.log

build

# Mac
*~
.DS_Store
```

My .gitignore_global is in git config:

```
$ git config -l
core.excludesfile=/Users/marcos/.gitignore_global
```

My repo is not inside another repo.
Why is Git ignoring my Makefile?

Comment: What about the file `.git/info/exclude`?

Comment: Thanks, @dusan. There was a line in this file with Makefile. I removed it. Could you reply my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [gitignore manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) (emphasis mine):

> Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern. When deciding
> whether to ignore a path, git normally checks gitignore patterns **from
> multiple sources**, with the following order of precedence, from highest
> to lowest (within one level of precedence, the last matching pattern
> decides the outcome):
>
> (...)
>
> - Patterns read from **$GIT_DIR/info/exclude**.

So you have to check the contents of `.git/info/exclude`.